# Bubble sorting a singly linked list which contains a string in each node, in C?

Tags: c, string, singly-linked-list, bubble-sort

What is the correct method of sorting a linked list in which EA node contains  a different string?

Everything related to Bubble sort on stackoverflow considers only one character or digit.How is bubble sort adjusted for strings.

```
void bubble_sort( struct dictionary_entry * head )
{
    struct dictionary_entry * selector;
    int swapd;
    int i; 
    int ooseven;
    char tword[5];
    char tword2[5]; 

    while ( swapd != 0 )
    {
        swapd = 0;
        selector = head;
        while ( selector->next_entry != NULL )
        { 
            memcpy( tword, selector->next_entry->four_letters, 5 ); 
            memcpy( tword2, selector->next_entry->next_entry->four_letters, 5 ); 
        }

        for ( i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
        {
            ooseven = tolower( tword[i] ) - tolower( tword2[i] );

            if ( ooseven > 0 )
            {
                swap( selector,
                      selector->next_entry,
                      selector->next_entry->next_entry,
                      selector->next_entry->next_entry->next_entry );

                i = 5;
            }
            else if ( ooseven < 0 )
            {
                i = 5;
            }
        }
        selector = selector->next_entry;
    }
}

void swap( struct dictionary_entry * a,
           struct dictionary_entry * b,
           struct dictionary_entry * c,
           struct dictionary_entry * d )
{
    *a = *c;
    *c = *b;
    *b = *d;
}
```

If you believe this question is answered by the medium of the answers containing bubble sort with single characters and digits can you explain how that format is the basis for linked lists with strings.

Here is my full code if you want to take a look at it. Be warned it does contain a lot of comments.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct dictionary_entry
{
    //int number_of_letters;
    char four_letters[5];
    struct dictionary_entry * next_entry;
} dictionary_entry;

char sentence[120][120];
char word[120];
char temp_word;
char four_letters[5] = {'\0'};
int word_number;
int number_of_words = -1;
int number_of_letters;
int letter_a;
int letter_b;
void scan();
void print();
void reverse();
void alphabetized();
void display( struct dictionary_entry * head );
void initialize();
void add( struct dictionary_entry ** head, char * four_letters );
void sentence_into_list();
void swap( struct dictionary_entry * a, struct dictionary_entry * b, struct dictionary_entry * c, struct dictionary_entry * d );
void bubble_sort( struct dictionary_entry * head );
struct dictionary_entry * head = NULL;

int main()
{
    //Prompt for user and organization of visual output.
    printf( "Type a sentence then press enter:\n\n" );
    scan();//
    printf( "\nA." ); //
    print();////
    printf( "\n\nB." ); //
    reverse();//
    printf( "\n\nC." ); //
    alphabetized();//
    printf( "\n\n" ); //
    //initialize();//
    sentence_into_list();//
    display( head );
    bubble_sort( head );
    display( head );
    return 0;
}

void scan()
{
    for ( word_number = 0;; word_number++ )
    {
        scanf( "%s", sentence[word_number] );
        number_of_words++;

        if ( getchar() == '\n' )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void print()
{
    for ( word_number = 0; word_number <= number_of_words; word_number++ )
    {
        printf( "%s ", sentence[word_number] );
    }
}

void reverse()
{
    for ( word_number = number_of_words; word_number >= 0; word_number-- )
    {
        printf( "%s ", sentence[word_number] );
    }
}

void alphabetized()
{
    for ( word_number = 0; word_number <= number_of_words; word_number++ )
    {
        strcpy( word, sentence[word_number] );
        number_of_letters = strlen( word );

        for ( letter_a = 0; letter_a < number_of_letters - 1; letter_a++ )
        {
            for ( letter_b = letter_a + 1; letter_b < number_of_letters; letter_b++ )
            {
                // This section compares the two letters.
                int  sentence = tolower( word[letter_a] ) - tolower( word[letter_b] );

                if ( sentence == 0 )
                {
                    sentence = word[letter_a] - word[letter_b];
                }

                if ( sentence > 0 )
                {
                    temp_word = word[letter_a];
                    word[letter_a] = word[letter_b];
                    word[letter_b] = temp_word;
                }
            }
        }

        printf( "%s ", word );
    }
}

//
// PART TWO OF THE KEIL PROGRAMMING CHALLENGE
//

void add( struct dictionary_entry ** head, char * four_letters ) // do I need wordl and fletters in here?
{
    // I changed add from struct to void
    struct dictionary_entry * new_entry = malloc( sizeof( struct dictionary_entry ) );
    // I have to have code that passes first four letter and the amount of letters here but can i use two portions for both
    // the original sentence and the new additions?

    //new_entry->number_of_letters = number_of_letters;//_temp;?
    memcpy( new_entry->four_letters, four_letters, 5 );
    new_entry->next_entry = *head;
    *head = new_entry;
    // error return head;
}

void sentence_into_list()
{
    for ( word_number = 0; word_number <= number_of_words; word_number++ )
    {
        // number_of_letters = strlen(word);
        four_letters[4] = '\0';
        memcpy( four_letters, sentence[word_number], 4 );
        add( &head, four_letters );
    }
}

void display( struct dictionary_entry * head )
{
    struct dictionary_entry * current;
    current = head;

    if ( current != NULL )
    {
        printf( "Stack:" );

        do
        {
            printf( "%s ", current->four_letters );
            current = current->next_entry;
        }
        while ( current != NULL );

        printf( "\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The Stack is empty\n" );
    }
}


void bubble_sort( struct dictionary_entry * head ) //alphabetized
{
    //declaration of used variables
    struct dictionary_entry * selector; // for node selection
    int swapd; // for complete alphabetized contidion lol condition*
    int i; //for progression in word comparison
    int ooseven; // trying for the alphabetization result
    char tword[5], tword2[5]; //for word comparison

    //until alphabetized( when there are 0 swaps)
    while ( swapd != 0 )
    {
        swapd = 0;

        //list start
        selector = head;

        while ( selector->next_entry != NULL ) //list progression
        {
            memcpy( tword, selector->next_entry->four_letters, 5 );
            memcpy( tword2, selector->next_entry->next_entry->four_letters, 5 );
            //list pair comparison
            //2nd, dont need this->//if () //a little lost going top down so ill do bottom up, 1st

        }

//goes trhough word
        for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            ooseven = tolower( tword[i] ) - tolower( tword2[i] );

            //compares two letters //3 cases
            if ( ooseven > 0 )
            {
                swap( selector, selector->next_entry, selector->next_entry->next_entry, selector->next_entry->next_entry->next_entry );
                //end word comparison
                i = 5;
            }
            else if ( ooseven < 0 )
            {
                //end word comparison
                i = 5;
            }

            //dont need this caseif(tword[i]=tword2[i])
            //continue through word
        }

        selector = selector->next_entry; //progression abstraction
    }

}

void swap( struct dictionary_entry * a, struct dictionary_entry * b, struct dictionary_entry * c, struct dictionary_entry * d )
{
    *a = *c; //do i need to *a *c?
    *c = *b;
    *b = *d;
}
```

Comment: If using integers or single characters, how do you do the comparison when sorting? If you have two strings, how do you compare them? If you know both of these things, separate, then just combine that knowledge.

Comment: Reformatted the code using `astyle --style=ansi --indent-switches --indent-preprocessor --pad-oper --pad-paren-in --pad-header --unpad-paren --convert-tabs --break-blocks --add-brackets --align-pointer=middle` plus some manual touches. [`Astyle`](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) is free and can pretty-print other languages as well, I suggest you give it a try. Don't be sorry for the comments, they are the best part of your code. *Any* code, really. ;-)

Comment: Thanks DevSolar :) and Some programmer dude. Ill give it ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the actually selected node with the next node with the help of:

```
if((strcmp(node.String1,node.String2) >0 ){
  //Statements
}
```

When you use this you can sort your list alphabetically